# for loop of ListView not iterating through data in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

[code which not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFp7E.png)

this code is not working, i don't know what is wrong in my code.

[Views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ME0Xb.png)

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Comment: Thankyou for suggestion, i will ask questions in good format from now on.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define the **model name** on the view.Add the **model name** and try to add custom **context_object_name**. For reference check this

```
class BookListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Book
    context_object_name = 'my_book_list'   # your own name for the list as a template variable
    queryset = Book.objects.filter(title__icontains='war')[:5] # Get 5 books containing the title war
    template_name = 'books/my_arbitrary_template_name_list.html'  # Specify your own template name/location
```

Comment: i tried changes you suggested but still not working

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify which model to create `ListView`. Here in your case define `model=Post` as

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

class PostList(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/index.html'
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by("-created_on")
```

Or you can also use `get_queryset()` as

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

class PostList(ListView):

    # specify the model
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/index.html'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super(PostList, self).get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        qs = qs.filter(status=1).order_by("-created_on")
        return qs
```

Comment: i tried changes you suggested but still not working

Comment: Not working means data not shown or did you get any error ?

Comment: didn't get any error, data not reflecting on my webpage